# "Column Count doesn't match value count at row 1" E

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I've encountered an error and I'm not able to figure out my mistake. I've done my research and haven't found an appropriate answer for my question.

This is my code:

```
private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    String CN, CNo, MN, NT, SNo, VIP, T, D;
    CN = TF1.getText();
    CNo = TF2.getText();
    MN = TF3.getText();
    NT = TF4.getText();
    SNo = TF5.getText();
    VIP = TF6.getText();
    T = TF7.getText();
    D = TF8.getText();

    try
    {
        Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/devika", "root", "rockgirl12");
        Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        String query = "INSERT INTO Maintenance VALUES ('"+CN+"',"+CNo+",'"+MN+"',"+NT+",'"+SNo+"','"+VIP+"','"+T+"','"+D+"');";
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Record added succesfully!");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
    }   
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is I'm adding data to my SQL database through a form I designed in Java Netbeans. I've attached the form I've created here.
[My Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yplDd.png)

Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what the error says. The number of columns and the fields in valules do not match. This sort of insert without specifing the column names isn't the best practice by any stretch. You should do

```
String query = "INSERT INTO Maintenance(col1, col2, col3, col4,..) VALUES ('"+CN+"',"+CNo+",'"+MN+"',"+NT+",'"+SNo+"','"+VIP+"','"+T+"','"+D+"');";
```

In fact, you shouldn't be doing this sort of string concatenation either. It's far better to use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). The current approach does not ensure that the data is properly escaped before being saved.

Comment: Pretty sure that the values he posted are actually the columns + value

Comment: Glad to have helped